# How to edit price function html in magento?

Tags: frontend, price

Currently price showing like:

```
<span class="price">$589.00</span>
```

i want currency to bit little than other fonts and i should be superlative?
like:

`<span class="price"><sup>$</sup>589.00</span>`

From where do i get that file?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How? Please share the details with us. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The currency symbol is defined in `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/_your locale_.xml`, but I would not change it there. This will modify it everywhere and at least in pdfs you will get the tags displayed instead of HTML. Simplest way would be to achieve it via the :first-letter css pseudo-selector:

```
.price:first-letter
{ 
  //style here
}
```

Browser support is pretty good - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

Comment: Its not working on my site. I have checked above link on Firefox working perfectly but not on my site

Comment: Are you sure you are writing the proper CSS selector?

Comment: See
`.product-view .product-shop .price-box .price:first-letter {
    font-size: 200% !important;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Looking inside `design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`, it seems all prices are rendered by calling `currency(...)` inside `Mage_Core_Helper_Data`

```
public static function currency($value, $format = true, $includeContainer = true)
{
    return self::currencyByStore($value, null, $format, $includeContainer);
}
```

`currency(...)` then calls `currencyByStore(...)`:

```
public static function currencyByStore($value, $store = null, $format = true, $includeContainer = true)
{
    ...
    $value = $store->convertPrice($value, $format, $includeContainer);
    ...
}
```

`currencyByStore(...)` calls `convertPrice()` inside `Mage_Core_Model_Store`:

```
public function convertPrice($price, $format = false, $includeContainer = true)
{
    ...
    if ($this->getCurrentCurrency() && $format) {
        $value = $this->formatPrice($value, $includeContainer);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

`convertPrice(...)` calls `formatPrice(...)`:

```
public function formatPrice($price, $includeContainer = true)
{
    if ($this->getCurrentCurrency()) {
        return $this->getCurrentCurrency()->format($price, array(), $includeContainer);
    }
    return $price;
}
```

which eventually calls `format(...)`, the format method takes in an options array that gets passed all the way down to `Zend_Currency` inside `/lib/Zend/Currency.php`

```
/**
 * Options array
 *
 * The following options are available
 * 'position'  => Position for the currency sign
 * 'script'    => Script for the output
 * 'format'    => Locale for numeric output
 * 'display'   => Currency detail to show
 * 'precision' => Precision for the currency
 * 'name'      => Name for this currency
 * 'currency'  => 3 lettered international abbreviation
 * 'symbol'    => Currency symbol
 * 'locale'    => Locale for this currency
 * 'value'     => Money value
 * 'service'   => Exchange service to use
 *
 * @var array
 * @see Zend_Locale
 */
```

Notice the `'symbol'    => Currency symbol` and:

```
// Constants for defining what currency symbol should be displayed
const NO_SYMBOL     = 1;
const USE_SYMBOL    = 2;
const USE_SHORTNAME = 3;
const USE_NAME      = 4;
```

What you can do is override a the `currency()`, `currencyByStore()`, `convertPrice()` and `formatPrice()` to handle an extra parameter, a new options array and set `symbol => 1` from inside `price.phtml` and then you would be able to do `<span class="price"><sup>$</sup>589.00</span>`

I haven't tested/tried anything, just followed the function calls so this might not be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Progressive enhancement option: you could target the price block with JS, find the price strings, and adjust the DOM by wrapping the first character with the `<sup>` tag.

This would give you more layout control in CSS than `:first-letter` and have roughly equivalent fallback.

Comment: I've used this before, but it's not a general solution. It works only on specific currencies and locale. For some locale the currency symbol contains more than 1 char and it also can be placed after the value. For example: `22.99 RON`